# iPhone Objective C - Differences between Ringer volume and In-App Volume

Tags: iphone, audio, volume

iPhone has Ringer volume.
My app plays a few different sounds.
Is there a way to set different volume for my app (not related to iPhone's Ringer volume).

Are there any differences between iPhone Ringer volume and in app volume?

Answer (score 1):

There are two straight forward ways to play audio on the iphone (IOs device).
The more flexible is [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/), this will allow for playing simultaneous audio streams with independent volume control. The other is to play audio at the system volume level (like your ringer) using [Sound Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html) check out Apple's [AV docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html).